# QImage setting alpha in PNG with transparency

Tags: qt, transparency

I'm trying to draw an image over another (and that part works) but before I draw the overlay image I want to reduce the opacity of it. This is where I'm having trouble. My overlay images are PNG and they themselves have transparent areas, otherwise the content of them is black. In Qt I'm looping through every pixel and I'm having trouble determining if the pixel is transparent or not -- it tells me every pixel is black with full alpha. I've tried checking both the pixel color and alpha but I must be doing it wrong. Searching hasn't lead to a solution. Here's my little loop I'm using:

```
// Set Alpha
for (int x = 0; x < overlay.width(); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < overlay.height(); y++)
    {
        pixelColor = QColor(overlay.pixel(x,y));

        if (pixelColor.alpha() == 255)
        {
            overlay.setPixel(x, y, QColor(0,0,0,200).rgba());
            //qDebug() << "Not Skipped";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Skipped";
        }
    }
}
```

QImage says my overlay image format is Format_ARGB32. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? According to the Qt docs I should be able to use alpha(), but it gives me 255 for every single pixel. Maybe I'm getting the color wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the [`QColor(QRgb)` constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#QColor-3):

> Constructs a color with the value color. The alpha component is ignored and set to solid.

You have this problem because `QImage::pixel(int,int)` returns a `QRgb`. You should use `QImage::pixelColor(int,int)` instead (if available, was introduced in Qt 5.6), or use a `QRgb` directly, like this:

```
QRgb col = image.pixel(x,y);
if(qAlpha(col) == 255) {}
```

Note that if you want to decrease the opacity of an image, you can always [change the QPainter opacity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setOpacity).

Comment: That works, thanks for the explanation and I will also check out that link.

Comment: That's a tricky issue and an underhanding trap. For the record: Wouldn't have been usage of [`QImage::pixelColor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixelColor-1) (instead of `QImage::pixel()`) a sufficient fix?

Comment: @Scheff definitely! however, note that `QImage::pixelColor()` was introduced in Qt 5.6, which postdates this question/answer. that's probably a better solution now, though. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Oops, I didn't care about the Qt version. Cannot upvote - already done. ;-)