# Qt: PNG image transparency lost after opening

Tags: qt, png, qimage

I'm trying to open a PNG image using QT but the alpha values for the pixels is always 255 even when the image is blank (i.e., the alpha value should be 0)

I tried converting the image to ARGB format after loading but that didn't help. Here is an example of a blank png I'm trying to load:

Image:

[image]

```
QImage im = QImage("JGbVc0r.png");
int p1 = 20;
int p2 = 20;
QImage img = im.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
qInfo()<<qRed(img.pixel(p1,p2))<<qBlue(img.pixel(p1,p2))<<qGreen(img.pixel(p1,p2))<<qAlpha(img.pixel(p1,p2));
```

The expected output is 
    0 0 0 0
but I get
    255 255 255 255

Any suggestions on how to get the desired output? Thanks in advance. I'm using Qt 5.11.

Comment: If `im.format() == QImage::Format_ARGB32` then the loaded image is already in that format, and the conversion is pointless. `im.hasAlphaChannel()` shows that your image does have an alpha channel. When I load that file into a QImage and use the getters `qRed` etc., I get 0.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021966/qimage-setting-alpha-in-png-with-transparency I tested using Qt 5.12, so perhaps this changed recently.

Comment: That the alpha is zero does not imply that the image is black.

Comment: @eyllanesc The stated problem is that the alpha is expected to be 0 but is instead 255.

Comment: @replete Do you know how they created the image? How are you sure that the alpha component must be 0?

Comment: @eyllanesc The OP states the image has that form, i.e. that the image should be blank. Note OP says blank not black. I opened the OP's image and found this assertion to be true. The problem we are trying to solve is why the OP reads 255 for pixel alpha instead of 0, which is the correct alpha value in OP's image.

Comment: I tested dumping an image with `QImage::pixel()` in Qt5.9 and Qt5.11 with a small png file, I have composed before in GIMP. Alphas are supplied correctly. I also included the (in my case) useless `QImage img = im.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);` which didn't change anything. Just an idea, did you consider that upper left corner is pixel(0, 0)? Not that you are victim of an off-by-one-error...

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments. It's very useful to know that none of you were able to reproduce the issue.Still not sure what my issue is though. I understand that alpha =  0 doesn't necessarily mean the color is black. I should mention that I created this image with Qt with Qcolor(0,0,0,0). Do you know if there are any Qt settings that can cause this behavior?

Comment: Stupid question: Are you sure that your image could be loaded at all? After having this idea, I extended my answer. (I believe you should've noticed if that would've been the issue.)

Comment: Thank you all so much for all the suggestions. I ended up reinstalling Qt 11.3 and it works as expected now. Still not sure what was causing it but happy it works

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the issue of OP.

Unfortunately, imgur.com is blocked in my company (where I stumbled first into this question). Hence, I started with a small sample image I prepared on my own in GIMP.

[image: Sample Image made in GIMP (8x8, RGBA)] ← It's really small: 8x8 pixel with RGBA channels.

Next, I made a small sample application to inspect the outcome in a `QImage` – `testQImageRGBA.cc`:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#include <QtWidgets>

void dump(
  const QImage &qImg, int row, int col,
  std::function<void(const QImage&, int, int)> dumpPixel)
{
  qDebug() << qImg;
  const int nR = qImg.height(), nC = qImg.width();
  const int iR0 = row >= 0 ? row : 0;
  const int iRN = row >= 0 ? row + 1 : nR;
  const int iC0 = col >= 0 ? col : 0;
  const int iCN = col >= 0 ? col + 1 : nC;
  std::cout << "Dump of rows [" << iR0 << ", " << iRN << "),"
    << " cols [" << iC0 << ", " << iCN << ")\n"
    << "Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'\n";
  for (int iR = iR0; iR < iRN; ++iR) {
    for (int iC = iC0; iC < iCN; ++iC) {
      dumpPixel(qImg, iR, iC);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::function<void(const QImage&, int, int)> dumpPixelOP // OPs flavor
    = [](const QImage &qImg, int iR, int iC) {
      std::cout << std::hex << "_#"
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << qRed(qImg.pixel(iC, iR))
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << qGreen(qImg.pixel(iC, iR))
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << qBlue(qImg.pixel(iC, iR))
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << qAlpha(qImg.pixel(iC, iR));
    };
  std::function<void(const QImage&, int, int)> dumpPixel // my flavor
    = [](const QImage &qImg, int iR, int iC) {
      const QColor pixel = qImg.pixelColor(iC, iR);
      std::cout << std::hex << " #"
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << pixel.red()
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << pixel.green()
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << pixel.blue()
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << pixel.alpha();
    };
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  const QStringList args = app.arguments();
  const QString filePath = args.size() > 1 ? args[1] : "smiley.8x8.rgba.png";
  const int row = args.size() > 2 ? args[2].toInt() : -1;
  const int col = args.size() > 3 ? args[3].toInt() : -1;
  const bool useDumpOP = args.size() > 4;
  QImage qImg(filePath);
  qImg = qImg.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
  dump(qImg, row, col, useDumpOP ? dumpPixelOP : dumpPixel);
  return 0;
}
```

and a Qt project file – `testQImageRGBA.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQImageRGBA.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQImageRGBA.pro

$ make && ./testQImageRGBA
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQImageRGBA.o testQImageRGBA.cc
g++  -o testQImageRGBA.exe testQImageRGBA.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
QImage(QSize(8, 8),format=5,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=32,byteCount=256)
Dump of rows [0, 8), cols [0, 8)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
 #00000000 #00000000 #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #00000000 #00000000
 #00000000 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff #00000000
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #0000ffff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #0000ffff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ff0000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ff0000ff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ff0000ff #ff0000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #00000000 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff #00000000
 #00000000 #00000000 #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #00000000 #00000000
```

The dump reflects exactly what I have drawn in GIMP. Please, note the pixels of corners which are black transparent.

I prepared a CMake source file `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(QImageRGBA)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQImageRGBA testQImageRGBA.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQImageRGBA Qt5::Widgets)
```

and compiled the same source in VS2017. Tested in `cmd.exe` on Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>set PATH=%PATH%;D:\Scheff\Qt\5.11.2\msvc2017_64\bin;$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)

C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>build-VS2017\Debug\testQImageRGBA.exe
Qt Version: 5.11.2
QImage(QSize(8, 8),format=5,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=32,sizeInBytes=256)
Dump of rows [0, 8), cols [0, 8)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
 #00000000 #00000000 #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #00000000 #00000000
 #00000000 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff #00000000
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #0000ffff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #0000ffff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ff0000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ff0000ff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ff0000ff #ff0000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff
 #00000000 #000000ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #ffff00ff #000000ff #00000000
 #00000000 #00000000 #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #000000ff #00000000 #00000000

C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>
```

There is effectively no difference.

---

Once at home (with access to imgur.com), I downloaded the image of OP [JGbVc0r.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4D6b.png) and tried again.

First in cygwin64:

```
$ make && ./testQImageRGBA JGbVc0r.png 20 20   
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Qt Version: 5.9.4
QImage(QSize(1000, 1000),format=5,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=4000,byteCount=4000000)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
 #00000000
```

then in VS2017 and `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>build-VS2017\Debug\testQImageRGBA.exe JGbVc0r.png 20 20
Qt Version: 5.11.2
QImage(QSize(1000, 1000),format=5,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=4000,sizeInBytes=4000000)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
 #00000000
```

OP stated:

> The expected output is 0 0 0 0

and that's exactly what I got.

---

[replete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9088793/replete) provided an interesting hint about a trap concerning `QColor::QColor(QRgb)` which is subject of Q/A

[SO: QImage setting alpha in PNG with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25022082/7478597).

However, I came to the conclusion that this shouldn't be the issue here because in OPs code

```
qInfo()<<qRed(img.pixel(p1,p2))<<qBlue(img.pixel(p1,p2))<<qGreen(img.pixel(p1,p2))<<qAlpha(img.pixel(p1,p2));
```

- [`QImage::pixel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixel) is used which returns `QRgb`
- [`qRed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qRed), [`qGreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qGreen), [`qBlue()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qBlue), and [`qAlpha()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qAlpha) take a `QRgb` and return an `int`.

Hence, the underhanding `QColor::QColor(QRgb)` is simply not involved. To eliminate my last doubts, I simply tried this as well in cygwin:

```
$ make && ./testQImageRGBA JGbVc0r.png 20 20 dumpLikeOP  
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Qt Version: 5.9.4
QImage(QSize(1000, 1000),format=5,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=4000,byteCount=4000000)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
_#00000000
```

and in VS2017 and `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>build-VS2017\Debug\testQImageRGBA.exe JGbVc0r.png 20 20 dumpLikeOP
Qt Version: 5.11.2
QImage(QSize(1000, 1000),format=5,depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,bytesPerLine=4000,sizeInBytes=4000000)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
_#00000000
```

So, I simply cannot reproduce the issue of OP although I tried hard.

The OP might take my code to test as well. Either OP overlooked something else which was not exposed in question or there is a specific issue on OP's system.

---

My last (desperate) idea was to check what happens if `QImage` was simply not loaded (e.g. due to file not found).

In cygwin:

```
$ make && ./testQImageRGBA ImageNotFound.png 20 20           
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Qt Version: 5.9.4
QImage(null)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
QImage::pixelColor: coordinate (20,20) out of range
 #000000ff

$ make && ./testQImageRGBA ImageNotFound.png 20 20 dumpLikeOP
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
Qt Version: 5.9.4
QImage(null)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
_#00303900
```

Please note, that the out of range accesses are notified on console. Beside of this, the code seems to run properly but returns any arbitrary values.

In VS2017 / `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>build-VS2017\Debug\testQImageRGBA.exe ImageNotFound.png 20 20
Qt Version: 5.11.2
QImage(null)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
QImage::pixelColor: coordinate (20,20) out of range
 #000000ff

C:\Users\Scheff\tests\misc\Qt\QImageRGBA>build-VS2017\Debug\testQImageRGBA.exe ImageNotFound.png 20 20 dumpLikeOP
Qt Version: 5.11.2
QImage(null)
Dump of rows [20, 21), cols [20, 21)
Pixel format: '#RRGGBBAA'
_#QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
00QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
30QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
39QImage::pixel: coordinate (20,20) out of range
00
```

The order of output changed a bit. Beside of this, I even got the same "arbitrary" values (which IMHO means nothing).

Comment: An excellent and instructive investigation. Perhaps it is worth pointing out that if indeed the (255, 255, 255, 255) is the result of garbage from a QImage that failed to load, this could have been avoided by testing with `QImage::isNull()` after construction. It's not so unusual when using a new development environment that the working directory isn't what you expect: `QImage img("filenameWithoutDirectory.png")` has trapped me too. It's also a good reminder that if your environment doesn't show the console, that's a problem.

Comment: @replete I agree in general. However, OP used `qInfo()` and therefore I assume she/he had console in focus... ;-)